# How to dynamically assign delay value for waitKey() so I get the correct fps?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a video and I want to process the frames.

```
VideoCapture capture("movie.mpg");

while(true) {
  Mat frame;
  capture >> frame;

  // This may take some time to finish
  processFrame(frame);

  if (waitKey(80) == 'q')
    break;
}
```

The problem is, using the hardcoded delay `waitKey(80)` will results with incorrect fps for the video. For example, the above code try to display the video with 12 frames per second, but if `processFrame()` takes some time to finish, the fps would be lower and the video looks lagging.

I need to do some calculation for the delay value here. How do you dynamically assign the value so the fps will stay at 12? Thanks.

Comment: You can time the function and subtract that.

Comment: It might perhaps make more sense to do your frame processing in one thread, and handle user interaction in another. This will be significantly harder to implement, but will result in a more responsive UI and a worker thread that can work as fast as you want it to.

Comment: @Rook  Not hard.  Move processFrame to a loop in another thread.  Have it sleep until kicked by the main loop (wait on bit or Event, depending on what libraries its using).  Just need a little code to start the thread and tell it when to exit.

Comment: @stark: from bitter experience, safely multithreading code is never entirely as easy as it first appears ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the actual [FPS of the video](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv-videocapture-get) by querying the capture interface:

```
double fps = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
```

and you can also discover the total amount of frames in the video with `CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT`.

With that info you can do a simple calculation and find out the exact amount of time to delay.